# Vue js routes do not get updated after editing routes index.js file

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

I'm using Vue within Laravel to build SPA
but I can't get newly added routes into my app, and Vue shows me the old routes only when I use Vue developer tools.
I tried to clear Laravel cache and npm cache but nothing changed

Comment: most times you just need to clear browser cache if web pack compiled your js successfully.

Comment: it worked actually

Comment: May I know what worked please

Comment: exactly as you said, also I cleared Cloudflare cache which is connected to my website.